# Linux socket doesn't close

Tags: linux, sockets, unbind

i have a problem. I run a TCP server in linux. I close the socket by close(socket) call. But when I try to rebind again, bind call fails with errno 98 => port is already binded. How should i unbind that socket?

Comment: Might this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208581/socket-listen-doesnt-unbind-in-c-under-linux

Answer (score 2):

You have to set SO_REUSEADDR option on the socket, see [here](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml).

Comment: Thank you, it really helped. Strange that it is not needed in Windows if I run the application there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775638/using-so-reuseaddr-what-happens-to-previously-open-socket) for some discussion.